# Is it possible to access the RGB values of the EV3 Light Sensor?

Tags: ev3, sensor-colour

I'm following a line with the LEGO EV3 Color Sensor in Reflected-light mode, I need to stop the robot when it detects a green tile in the ground, but I didn't succeeded in differentiating Green and Black, can I access the RGB values of the sensor, or in some way differentiate those colors?

Comment: Please aim to be as descriptive as possible in your question title to get the best possible answers. I've changed the title to what I believe is the subject of your answer, if this isn't the case, please feel free to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Green does tend to be tricky on the LEGO EV3 Color sensor. [Example](http://forums.usfirst.org/showthread.php?23642-EV3-Color-Sensor-and-green-line)

Here are some suggestions:

- Build a shroud to eliminate ambient light. I have seen people use electrical tape for this or build something from LEGO parts.
- Using the raw RGB values, convert to HSV (there is a link in Example 1 for this).
- Use the [algorithm for the NXT color sensor from the EV3 source code](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3sources/blob/master/lms2012/c_input/source/c_input.c#L1388). It will probably have to be adjusted a bit for differences in the sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes try this. [Color RGB](http://mindcuber.com/mindcub3r/ColorSensorRGB-v1.00.ev3b) This is the Color RGB sensor block. Installation instruction can refer from [here](http://mindcuber.com/mindcub3r/mindcub3r.html#ColorSensorRGBBlock)